# Reserving A Theater Seat

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, multithreading

Think booking a ticket at a movie.  There are x number of open seats, when you come to the site, I want to reserve one of the seats for a period of time.

I have a Private Internal API and a Public API.  The Public API would respond to the application that seeks to reserve a seat, by calling the internal API and then place that seat in a "Being Booked" status.

My issue is that I have occasionally two people booking the same seat, and that results in one person entering all their information, and then being unable to finish their registration.

I have attempted to make my code thread safe but am still getting the odd duplicate assignment of the same seat.

I am calling my status update from my "Reserve" method as such:

`VisitStatusChangeResult visit_status_change_result = await ReserveSlotByLockedStatusUpdate(first_empty_seat);`

this is the status update method which I have attempted to add thread saftey to by using SemaphoreSlim:

```
private static SemaphoreSlim m_ReserveOnlineSlotStatusUpdateSemaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(initialCount: 1, maxCount: 1);


private async Task<VisitStatusChangeResult> ReserveSlotByLockedStatusUpdate(VisitQueryResult first_empty_seat)
{
  await m_ReserveOnlineSlotStatusUpdateSemaphore.WaitAsync();

  try
  {
    return await ChangeStatus(new VisitStatusUpdateModel
    {
      VisitID = first_empty_seat.ID,
      CurrentVisitStatusID = first_empty_online_visit.VisitStatusID,
      NewVisitStatusID = (int)VisitStatuses.BeingBooked
    });
  }
  finally
  {
    m_ReserveOnlineSlotStatusUpdateSemaphore.Release();
  }

}
```

Am I missing something where even with the SemaphoreSlim await, I can have two people grabing the same seat?

Comment: Do you store reservations info in database? If yes, why it is allowed (on database level) for such situation to occur?

Comment: Yes, the seats are each a row in a database with a fk of `VisitStatusID` which is what is being set to "BeingBooked" so we know that seat is reserved until the client books the seat, leaves the booking application, or they run out of time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, using in-memory locks to protect parallel access to the database resource is not very good idea - every database has it's own tools for such things. Most likely you have to use optimistic concurrency in this case, roughly like this:

```
update Visit set VisitStatusID = BeingBooked, ClientID = CurrentClientID where VisitStatusID = Free
```

So you know *who* is now booking this seat, and also, if so happened that this seat is already not free - this statement will return 0 (0 rows modified). You should check for this and act accordingly (notify client that this seat has already been taken and refresh the seats).

Second, your lock has no effect anyway. Nothing prevent for two clients to call `ReserveSlotByLockedStatusUpdate` *sequentially*, one after another, and still getting into trouble, because they will both reserve the same seat (unless you implement optimistic concurrency as above).

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer.  We do check the status on the seat for the next attempt at updating the status before updating, but this can still fall through?  If it helps any we are using mysql.

Comment: Yes, because between your check and update, row might has already been updated (unless you doing things like taking database row lock on row in question). But if you just make regular select followed by update - its not safe.

Comment: So really because of this external access (the DB) I should look to handle this via DB concurency methodologies.  If I wasn't hitting the DB I could stay within a threadsafe operation like I had tried?

Comment: Yes (though better to use regular lock instead of semaphore - if all was in memory, you wont need to do it asynchronously).

Comment: By the way, if you use Entity Framework - it supports optimistic concurrency for updates out of the box.